# Pulling Zabbix Data into csv file

Tags: python, zabbix, zabbix-api

Can't seem to find the correct syntax to get the request I need.

At this point I am able to connect to my Zabbix server via an API. I'm able to see all the data that I need which is confirmed by a simple print() function.

However, I am blanking at the way to get the data from the variable into a csv file.

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbiXAPI

        zapi = ZabbixAPI("example")
        zapi.login("example", "example")
    
    for hostInventory in zapi.host.get():
        print(hostInventory)
```

This then spits out about 500 lines of this approx - obviously redacted sensitive information:

```py
{'hostid': 'xxx', 'proxy_hostid': 'xxx', 'host': 'xxx', 'status': 'x', 'lastaccess': 'x', 'ipmi_authtype': 'x', 'ipmi_privilege': 'x', 'ipmi_username': 'x', 'ipmi_password': 'x', 'maintenanceid': 'x', 
'maintenance_status': 'x', 'maintenance_type': 'x', 'maintenance_from': 'x', 'name': 'x', 'flags': 'x', 'templateid': 'x', 'description': 'x', 'tls_connect': 'x', 'tls_accept': 'x', 'tls_issuer': 'x', 'tls_subject': 'x', 'proxy_address': 'x', 'auto_compress': 'x', 'custom_interfaces': 'x', 'uuid': 'x', 'inventory_mode': 'x'}
```

If I need to provide any further information please let me know. First time poster.

Comment: you have to learn standard module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or popular `pandas` - and this problem has nothing to do directly with Zabbix.

Comment: @furas I understand its not a problem with zabbix itself, however i'm more looking for the solution or the missing code that will allow me to write the data once i have it. Everything that I seem to have tried doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: if you found something and it doesn't work then you should show it in question - so we wouldn't have to waste time for methods which don't work for you. OR maybe we could fix these methods - if we know what error they gives.

Comment: I do apologise, i can only give a rundown of what I have tried as I have scrubbed it everytime the outcome either resulted in syntax errors or doesn't get me what I needed. I can edit the main post with this information if you think that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to learn standard module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or popular `pandas`
(and this problem has nothing to do directly with `Zabbix`).

With `pandas` it should be much simpler.

```
import pandas as pd

data = list( zapi.host.get() )
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Eventually you may have to use own code to create dictionaries

```
data = []

for hostInventory in zapi.host.get():
    item = {"hostid": hostInventory.hostid, ...}
    data.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Furas, seem to have run into an issue where it tells me that the object of type set is not JSON serializable.

I have tried using JSONpickle to encode and decode this however the end result always ends in the same output.

Comment: so you may have to create own code to convert it to normal dictionary with strings: `{"hostid": hostInventory.hostid, ...}` and this will need to use `for`-loop to create list with all dictionares.